# Aurelia/Typescript Pushing Model Properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have 2 separate api calls that return model properties. I need a way to basically put the 2 models into  1 single bucket that my view can take from . Like SQL Inner join a join basically . Any help in how to do would be greatly appreciated. - Jason

```
 upload(): void {
    try {
        var formData = new FormData()
        for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            formData.append('files', this.files[i]);
        }
        this._apiBureauModUpdate.PostFile(formData).then(uploadedMods => {

            for (let i = 0, u = null; u = uploadedMods[i]; i++) {
                   // u.Bureau = this.GetBureau(u.Bureau)


                this._apiPolicy.GetPolBase(u.Policy).then(p => {
                    if (p) {
                      //  var pol: any = {}
                      //  pol.UwOfC = p.UwOfc;
                      //  pol.DateEff = p.DateEff;
                      //  pol.DateExp = p.DateExp;
                      //  pol.mods = this.modsany[u.IndexId];
                      //  this.mods.push(pol)
                    }

                    });   


            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        this.running = false;
        this.runError = e;
    }

}
```

Comment: Define 'bucket'

Comment: so in this example todaysUploads would be my bucket I guess. Its a model object basically.                                                                '<div class="cardContent scroll-card">
            <ul>
                <li repeat.for="tu of todaysUploads" click.delegate="setSelecteHistoryId(tu.IndexId)" class="${(tu.IndexId===selectedHistoryId?'selected':'')}">
                    <p class="result-name">${GetBureau(tu.Bureau)} - ${tu.FileName}</p>
                    <span class="result-data">${tu.RecordCount}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>'